# Center a TabControl on a Form and a Panel on the TabControl

Tags: vb.net

A WindowsForm application with this setting on the Design view:

MainForm.WindowState = Maximized

TabControl.Dock = None

ControlPanel(Inside the TabControl).Dock = None

I need to center the TabControl on the Form and the Panel on the TabControl

Using

```
TabControl.Top = (Me.ClientSize.Height / 2)
TabControl.Left = (Me.ClientSize.Width / 2)
```

The TabControl it's shown far to the left and far below.

Almost the same result using Me.DisplayRectangle.Height / 2 and Me.DisplayRectangle.Width

Also tried with

```
TabControl.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None
```

as suggested on some sites but didn't work

Using

```
TabControl.Top = (Me.ClientSize.Height / 4)
TabControl.Left = (Me.ClientSize.Width / 4)
```

The TabControl looks more centered...

**What can be wrong? A setting on Design time?**

Comment: what exactly is `ControlPanel`?  What type of control?

Comment: Sorry, I dont follow - unless you are resizing the Tab when the form maximizes, the Panel at least should remain centered.  Also turn on Option Strict - `TabControl.Top = (Me.ClientSize.Height / 2)` is assigning a Double to an Int property

Comment: You did not center it.  TabControl.Top = (Me.ClientSize.Height - TabControl.Height) \ 2, same for left.

Comment: @Plutonix is just a Panel inside the TabPage

Comment: @Plutonix Option Strict on. Thanks, I also was assigning Integer to Single on another part of the code

Comment: @HansPassant That was the solution !! TabControl.Top = (Me.ClientSize.Height - TabControl.Height) \ 2 It seems Is also needed to subtract the TabControl Height and Width !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The red shows the height and width of the form, and the blue shows half of those dimensions. So using 1/2 doesn't make sense.

[image]

The correct math would involve the size of the tabcontrol

```
TabControl1.Top = (Me.ClientSize.Height - TabControl1.Height) \ 2
TabControl1.Left = (Me.ClientSize.Width - TabControl1.Width) \ 2
```

[image]

You could put it in the form's resize event and load

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    centerTabControlInForm()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
    centerTabControlInForm()
End Sub

Private Sub centerTabControlInForm()
    TabControl1.Top = (Me.ClientSize.Height - TabControl1.Height) \ 2
    TabControl1.Left = (Me.ClientSize.Width - TabControl1.Width) \ 2
End Sub
```

Similarly, you can do something like this with the panel relative to the tab control. You may also want to resize the controls as the form resizes, but that is outside the scope of your question...

Comment: It should be `(Me.ClientSize.Height - TabControl1.Height) \ 2)` (etc) so the result is an integer and will compile under Option Strict

Comment: Better 10 pts better ;)

Comment: @Verdolino Right!! The correct math would involve the size of the tabcontrol that was my mistake. Also thanks for the tip about Resize event. It's all OK now

"Similarly, you can do something like this with the panel relative to the tab control. You may also want to resize the controls as the form resizes, but that is outside the scope of your question..."

I will take care of the Panel too.